# Como fazer uma class interferir em outra com python

Tags: python, classes, variáveis, kivy

Estou querendo fazer um botão no estilo interruptor com kivy, quando um é verdadeiro, o outro é falso, porém, quando vou alterar uma variável na class do primeiro, ela não é alterada no segundo, e permanece com o valor original. Exemplicando:

```
c = 'NADA'

class A():

        c = 'CLASS A'        

class B():

        print(c)
        c = 'CLASS B'
        print(c)

x = A()
x = B()
print(c)
```

Tem como output:

```
NADA
CLASS B
NADA
```

Comment: Qual é o resultado que você espera?

Comment: Desculpe, acabei não deixando explícito, mas é como o amigo de baixo mostrou, 
`CLASS A `
`CLASS B `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Será necessário identificar que a variável `c` que se deseja alterar é da classe `A()`. Ao utilizar do jeito que você fez, está alterando a variável global criada no inicio do código.

Ficaria assim:

```
c = 'NADA'

class A():
    c = 'CLASS A'        
    print(c)

class B():
    A.c = 'CLASS B'
    print(A.c)

x = A()
x = B()
```

Resultando em:

```
CLASS A
CLASS B
```